# How to send emails from my website domain in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to send mail from my website domain(www.sample.com)
I have written below code. It is not returning any error. But it is not sending mail once I uploaded the pages in the server. Once click on email send, it is not getting any error, but not receiving the mail.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.sample.co.uk", 25);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("smtpuser@sample.co.uk", "pass@123");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

//Setting From , To and CC
mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("smtpuser@sample.co.uk", "MyWeb Site");
mail.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com"));
mail.CC.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail1@gmail.com"));

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

I am getting the "mailsend" response text in the page once calling the sending method.

Please help
Anjana

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: Could you make sure ***SMTP Host, Port Number, Username and Password*** are all valid?

Comment: If you are using IIS 6 smtp server have you made sure it is running on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfect for me. Make sure you have added a mail account on the smtp server and activated it.

```
private static string EMAIL_SERVER = "mailservername.mydomain.com";
    private static string EMAIL_NAME = "myMailAccount@mydomain.com";
    private static string EMAIL_PASSWORD = "complex_password123";
    private static string EMAIL_SEND_TO = "sample@mail.com";
    protected string SendMail()
    {

        try
        {

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage objMM = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            objMM.From = new MailAddress("fromMe@mail.com", "john doe");
            objMM.To.Add(new MailAddress(EMAIL_SEND_TO));    //Note: this To a collection
            objMM.Subject = "Subject1";
            objMM.Body = "Hello world this is my text";
            objMM.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(EMAIL_SERVER);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EMAIL_NAME, EMAIL_PASSWORD);
            smtp.Send(objMM);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return "Message can not be send couse of error: " + e.ToString();
        }


        return "Message is send.";

    }
```